# RuntimeError: Freetype library not found, Glumpy Python 3.6 w10

Tags: python, runtime-error, freetype, glumpy

My problem is the exact same with this: [Freetype library not found with Glumpy Python 3.6 Win 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013496/freetype-library-not-found-with-glumpy-python-3-6-win-10)

Someone answered below but I didn't understand what has to be done, can someone explain it better?
I found the file he mentioned in the comments but I don't know what to write and set the path.

I already did `pip install freetype-py` and currently using (2.0.0.post6) version and still having the error.

Comment: I solved the issue by simply installing linux operating system

Answer (score 1):

You just need to copy the FreeType package to ext package of glumpy.